# How can I use own located folders as volumes in docker artifactory container?

Tags: docker, artifactory

I'm following these instructions in order to run an artifactory container: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Running+with+Docker

It works and artifactory is up and running but in this way I cannot use my own host directory to be linked as container volumes. The guide says to use

```
-v /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/etc
-v /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/data
-v /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/backup
-v /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/logs
```

options when running the container but in this way I obtain that the volumes are stored in some /var/lib/docker/volumes/.. subfolders. What I'd like is to have these volumes mounted for example in my host's /opt/artifactory/

So I've tried to use the volume mapping in this way:

```
-v /opt/artifactory/etc:/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/etc
-v /opt/artifactory/data:/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/data
-v /opt/artifactory/backup:/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/backup
-v /opt/artifactory/logs:/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/logs
```

but I obtain this error:

```
** ERROR: Artifactory home folder not defined or does not exists at
```

Does anybody already tried this before? How can I manage it?

Thanks,
Michele.

Comment: FYI these issues seem to be fixed in v4.8.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Artifactory home folder not defined or does not exists at

That should be means `export ARTIFACTORY_HOME=/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory` has not be executed (whether or not you are using volumes).

That also mean you should execute `docker run` with a `-e ARTIFACTORY_HOME=/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory` environment option.

See also this [support thread](http://forums.jfrog.org/docker-compose-file-for-Artifactory-td7580537.html).

---

The [OP Mikyjpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4575233/mikyjpeg) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33755350/how-can-i-use-own-located-folders-as-volumes-in-docker-artifactory-container/33756440?noredirect=1#comment55321540_33756440):

> I eventually found the problem:
>   There is a file in the `/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/etc` folder of the container that sets all the environment variables. This file is erased by the volume mapping (as it does not exist on my host), it is recreated when the command starts but with a different content.
>   So I have copied this file from a working container, put into my host `etc` mapped volume and run again. And now it works.
>
> I was supposing that the `-v` option creates empty volumes in either cases but now I know that it is not true.

Comment: I've tried adding the -e parameter but I've another error: `** ERROR: Artifactory pid destination ARTIFACTORY_PID was not set in /etc/opt/jfrog/artifactory/default ! Please add it!`

Comment: @Mikyjpeg maybe a right issue. Check with which user that jfrog service is running. Just for testing, make sure default is created, and (again for testing) with a chmod 777.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand: as I do not mount any /etc/opt/jfrog... volumes, I suppose that it has to be "inside" the container (and so I cannot create it). How can I create if the container itself does not start?

Comment: @Mikyjpeg "How can I create if the container itself does not start?": simple: you `docker run` with `/bin/bash` as a parameter, to override the `CMD` of the image. The goal is to open an interactive session in which you can try to launch the service, but also see what is going on. If that does not work, you make a new Dockerfile, based on the image you are currently trying to run as a container. In that Dockerfile, you can override `ENTRYPOINT` and/or `CMD` in order to run by default a bash.

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not know that. I entered and I cannot find problems: my volumes are correctly mounted and have the right permission. I can also start artifactory without any problem. Maybe the problem is how it is started... How can I fix it if I don't do anything? I have try to run the command to start artifactory but it dies after tomcat is started because the command ends.

Comment: @Mikyjpeg try and docker inspect the container (that fails to start): see what its ENTRYPOINT and CMD are and make sure you replicate the exact command in your interactive bash session.

Comment: Ok, I find which command is run and now I have the same error. It seems that all the environment variables needed (ARTIFACTORY_HOME, TOMCAT_HOME, ARTIFACTORY_PID, ARTIFACTORY_USER) are not set. I cannot see how volume mapping can involves this.

Comment: @Mikyjpeg you can make a Dockerfile in which you define as many `ENV as you need, and test in that new image (based on the one you are currently using) if the presence of those environment variables improves the situation.

Comment: @Mikyjpeg Do you still have the same issue?

Comment: I eventually found the problem: there is a file in the /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/etc folder of the container that sets all the environment variables. This file is erased by the volume mapping (as it does not exist on my host), it is recreated when the command starts but with a different content. So I have copied this file from a working container, put into my host etc mapped volume and run again. And now it  works. I was supposing that the -v option creates empty volumes in either cases but now I know that it is not true. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: @Mikyjpeg Thank you for the feedback: I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.